# OpenGL with Android widgets contorls

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I would like to use an accelerated 2d Graphics (OpenGL) together with standard android controls widgets in order to interact with objects in OpenGL.

RayPicking is already implemented. Though I can select the objects.

But how does it work with views etc in order to use the standard controls of Android such as button, slider etc.?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL doesn't really interact at all with android widgets.

If you want to utilize both, you can use a `FrameLayout` and layout android widgets overtop of a GLSurfaceView, but they don't really interact. OpenGL has no idea about the widgets, and the widgets aren't controlled in any way by OpenGL.